# assistance using update method in php with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a simple option tag in html which lists all users held on the database when the user clicks donate i want to take the value entered and update the dontate_Total row relvant to that user with the value entered by the user in the donate label section.

here is my html

```
<table>

    <form>
    <tr><td><label>User:</label></td>
    <td>
    <select>
    <?php do{?>
    <option> <?php echo $rsNames['first_Name'];?> <?php echo $rsNames['last_Name'];?></option>
    <?php } while ( $rsNames= mysql_fetch_assoc($names_query))?>
    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><label>Donation £</label></td><td><input type="text" maxlength="9" value="0.00"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input id="submit" type="submit" value="DONATE" /></td></tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

the above works fine but now I want to run and update query when the user hits the DONATE input field. here is my sql statment which I believe wont work just after some advice

```
$donate_sql =UPDATE `donate` SET donate_Total=  donate_Total + $_GET['value'] WHERE first_Name = 'first_Name'   AND last_Name ='last_Name';
```

thanks

Comment: using a primary key in update clauses is better.

Comment: I just need some advice on how this would work for now, I could get the user_ID based on first + last then update but I just wanting it to work this way for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you?

### Edited (more profound) answer:

In your HTML, you have to give names to your fields in order to retrieve them from your PHP script i.e. give your `<select>` element a name (attribute), like this:

```
<select name="fullname">
```

Also, the nested `<option>` elements should have a "value" attribute, this is because you almost always want the identification of a field to be a unique ID (so there's no mistake when refering to a table row) but you want to show useful information to the user, such as a full name.

If you plan on using an ID, then your code (in HTML) should be updated to:

```
<option value="<?php echo $rsNames['id']; ?>"> <?php echo $rsNames['first_Name'];?> <?php echo $rsNames['last_Name'];?></option>
```

This will be outputed as:

```
<option value="1">John Doe</option>
<option value="2">Jane Doe</option>
```

Then in your PHP file, it would be much easier to write a query that updates exactly the user that you want.

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['fullname'];
$donate_sql = "UPDATE `donate` SET donate_Total = donate_Total + {$_GET['value']} WHERE id = $id";
mysql_query($donate_sql);

?>
```

If you don't plan on using an ID, you have to face the fact that if 2 users are called John Doe, you'll be updating the "total" amount of donation for both of them, and it's going to be a bit more complicated for you to parse the information.

Say you **DON'T** want to use an ID and you want to stick with your first and last name, then you would write something like:

```
<option value="<?php echo $rsNames['first_Name'] . '||' . $rsNames['last_Name'];?>"><?php echo $rsNames['first_Name'];?> <?php echo $rsNames['last_Name'];?></option>
```

Which would produce an output similar to:

```
<option value="John||Doe">John Doe</option>
<option value="Jane||Doe">Jane Doe</option>
<option value="Mary Jane||Doe">Mary Jane Doe</option>
```

The third `<option>` tag is an example of why you can't rely on spaces to parse first and last name; a person can have double name or double last name -- or both, as it is in my case ;-)

The separator || is an arbitrary one, the idea is to use one or more characters that are not likely going to be used as part of the name or the last name.

This approach (*which again, is a really **bad** one*) would require you to parse the first name and last name individually afterwards, so your script would end up being:

```
<?php

$name = $_GET['fullname']; //'fullname' is the name of our <select>
$name = explode('||',$name); //this returns an array, with each position defined by the || token

//$name is now an array(0=>'John',1=>'Doe') - for example.

//Get the first name
$firstName = $name[0]; //John

//Get the last name
$lastName = $name[1]; //Doe

//Finally, your SQL would be updated to be:
$donate_sql = "UPDATE `donate` SET donate_Total= donate_Total + {$_GET['value']} WHERE first_Name = '$firstName' AND last_Name ='$lastName'";

mysql_query($donate_sql);
?>
```

### Old answer

The quick answer is:

```
$donate_sql = "UPDATE `donate` SET donate_Total = donate_Total + {$_GET['value']} WHERE first_Name = 'first_Name' AND last_Name ='last_Name'";
```

And then using the `mysql_query($donate_sql);` function.

However as @hjpotter92 pointed out, you should (amongst other things) add an ID column to that table and set it as a primary key.

Also, you should keep in mind things like escaping values that come in your requests (`$_POST` and `$_GET`), so no SQL injection is applied to your query.

Hope this helps!

Cheers.

Comment: I know im just building my knowledge step at a time now would this get the value i want as I have a 2 value fields also do i just call the like this action = mysql_query($donate_sql); to my input type

Comment: I edited my answer to be a bit more precise. However, I do recommend you read a PHP tutorial, such as the one provided by w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_intro.asp this question could be easily answered with the examples there! I hope it works out for you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly using mysql_query function, try building the mysql statements, like `$donate_sql` built here by fsodano and then using an `echo $donate_sql;` to check, and then using the statement on a backup table. I prefer to do it this way, then messing up with the original work.

On a side note, your form consists of 'ALL' the first and last name combinations(I guess!), so there won't be any unique value for `$_GET['first_name']`

Do give the following statement a consideration!

```
$donate_sql = "UPDATE `donate` SET donate_Total = donate_Total + {$_GET['value']} WHERE first_Name = '{$_GET['first_Name']}' AND last_Name = '{$_GET['last_Name']}'";
echo $donate_sql;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
//code at the top of the document
if(isset($_POST['donation']) && $_POST['donation'] != '')
{
    $donation = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['donation']);
    $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['first_name']);
    $lname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['last_name']);
    $donate_sql = "UPDATE `donate` SET donate_Total = donate_Total + '{$donation}' WHERE first_Name = '{$fname}' AND last_Name = '{$lname'";
}

?>

<table>

    <form method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">

    <tr><td><label>User:</label></td>
    <td>
    <select>
    <?php do{?>
    <option> <?php echo $rsNames['first_Name'];?> <?php echo $rsNames['last_Name'];?></option>
    <?php } while ( $rsNames= mysql_fetch_assoc($names_query))?>
    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><label>Donation £</label></td><td><input name="donation" type="text" maxlength="9" value="0.00"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input id="submit" type="submit" value="DONATE" /></td></tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

Comment: these answers are still not doing what i set to do

Answer (score 0):

```
$value = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['value']);
$donate_sql = "UPDATE `donate` SET donate_Total = donate_Total + {$value}
```

adds a small layer of security to your query, but however give credit to @fsodano this is just an add on to his answer

Comment: Thanks for the Advice but I make use of value twice in this form so how do I know which one the SQL will fetch?

Comment: i did not completely understand your question, but from what i understand is that you have a $value variable declared twice in your code?

Comment: I'm trying to get the value entered by the user on the page under the label named donate which has a value attached to it which the user enters, the code is in the first post by myself.

Comment: you should add a name to the input field where the user enters the desired donation amount, i will post another answer with code example